# How can I make the bending smoother on my rigged arm?

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm creating a minecraft rig, and I'm a bit unique, and want some smoother bends on the arm as shown:

[image: Bend Arm]
Now, I'm not fond of the look of the inner part of the bend. I'd like to make the curve look better, so it's closer to the red line as shown. What ways can I accomplish this?

If not possible, I'd like it to be a sharp bend on the inner part. I'd highly prefer the smoother bend on the arm though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an additional bone from the middle of the vertical bone, with a "StretchTo" bone constraint tied  to the midpoint of the next bone. Then you can assign the vertices on the inner part of the elbow to the new bone. As the elbow bends, the bone (and the vertices bound to it) should deflect like you are asking.

Comment: I tried doing that, but not sure if it;s the right way. Is there an image I can rely on to accomplish this? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I have never seen anyone do this to put a bone more, this is usually solved with appropriate topology, I have sought that suggestion in practice and do not apply it, in fact I asked a professional and I wonder if I was serious or where there was listen to this, anyway it's just a comment

Answer (score 0):

### you can try something like this

subdivide the mesh as much as necessary until you achieve the effect most similar to what you are looking for.

you can also play with bone weights and give it a more proportional stretch

[image: example]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: The more geometry or tris you add, the softer the shape of the curvature in your mesh should be. That will depend on what you want to achieve. This is just an example to solve it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To get a nice curve you can first add subdivisions to each side of the mesh, that makes the weight of the new vertices average out.

[image]

So that the curve is not so pronounced you can recalculate the weight assigned to the vertices, to do that with the mesh selected go to Weight Paint mode, select all the bones (with the A key) and in the "Weights" menu select "Assign automatic from bones". Then in the same menu you have the option to smooth the weights, to do that you can select one of the bones or you can also select it from the mesh properties in the "Vertex Groups" panel, select a group and in the menu Weights > Smooth , you apply it as many times as necessary until you achieve the desired effect.

[image]

And finally you can add segments to the bones, to do that you select one or more bones and in the bone properties, in the Bendy Bones panel you increase the value of segments. If you have several bones selected you can increase the value of all of them at once while holding down the Alt key.

[image]